# Incorrect usage of "prevaricate"?

Tags: word-usage

Today, while reading an online article, I came across the following comment:

> Young people regret their mistakes. Old people regret not deciding. ***In
>   the contest of prevaricating*** between which choices we predict we will
>   one day celebrate and those we will one day regret and the alternative
>   of taking decisive action now, it is the latter that should win. Go
>   for it!

It seems to me that the word "prevaricate" is being used incorrectly here- my understanding is that the word denotes evasive behaviour. Am I correct in thinking that the above sentence makes no sense? I'm inclined to think that the poster should have used 'vacillate'instead.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're right: *vacillating* is the better word. I can't imagine what the poster was thinking. Then again, this being the Internet, thinking isn't the normal course of action.

Comment: -1 Can you cite the source? Obviously, it is not an authentic text and not expected to be one. Always try to include a link to the source.

Comment: @Kris: [Here's](http://syrasharif.policymic.com/profile/commentList?user_id=9142) the source. I see no good reason to suppose it's even from a native speaker - and given the *contest/context* "typo", I just think the whole question is Too Localised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know. Just reminding the OP; let's here from OP.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'authentic'..

Comment: @janexlane: I can't say exactly what Kris meant by "not authentic", but from my point of view the problem is the source is just a one-off post that already contains the far more "questionable" *contest/context* word-choice. As tchrist says in his answer, one definition of *prevaricate* is *equivocate* (that's in OED), so it's a bit ott to say your cited usage is "totally incorrect" on that score. In the end, we're just giving subjective opinions on this particular sentence (mostly negative, which I'm sure will gratify you! :)

Comment: I never said the word 'totally', and I didn't post the question for gratification purposes (at least not the kind implied). I didn't even realise that the word 'context' should have been used instead of 'contest'.English is neither my first nor second language, and so I assumed that the poster was making sense (at first), as in 'in the contest of prevaricating' being a legitimate phrase. I don't think 'subjective opinion' is an altogether valid premise for judging questions, as I've seen elaborated discussions based on subjectivity on many other ELS threads.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is indeed a catachrestic use of *prevaricate*, although I have seen it used that way before myself.   *Prevaricate* means to dissemble or in fact simply to lie. The dominant intransitive sense of that verb according to the OED is:

> To deviate from straightforwardness; to act or speak evasively; to quibble, shuffle, equivocate.

Interesting that I see *equivocate* mentioned there in *prevaricate*’s definition, as *equivocate* is sometimes also misused in the same sort of situation that you illustrated above.  I guess people just don’t know what those words really mean, but use them because they seem big and important.

I suspect that the word they ***meant*** to use was *vacillate*; it’s the one that fits there.  Some argument might perhaps also be made for *oscillate*, but that sounds more like something a machine or a wave-form might do than a person.

But *waver* is probably best.  It says exactly what is meant, and it doesn’t require extra syllables or some knowledge of Latin.

Comment: +1.  But whether OP adopts your emendation or sticks with her own, this will still be a horrible sentence in a horrible paragraph: an initial opposition followed by two pair of nested oppositions, climaxing in an invitation to select "the latter". I thought Graves & Hodge had killed this sort of thing.